# KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address using static map and std::make_pair

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, exc-bad-access

I get this error

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0xb064425c
```

When the following function is called:

```
const std::map<FunctionID, std::string> getEnumElementsStringRepresentation() {
  static bool is_initialized = false;
  static std::map<FunctionID, std::string> enum_string_representation; // Fails here
  if (false == is_initialized) {
    enum_string_representation.insert(std::make_pair(FunctionID.capabilities, "capabilities"));
    ... many more similar inserts
    is_initialized = true;
  }
  return enum_string_representation;
}
```

It appears to be a read/write error but I'm not sure the best way to debug.

Comment: Seems like an iPhone specific thing. I googled EXC_BAD_ACCESS and found lots of results. Have you researched that kind of stuff?

Comment: Yes, this isn't on an iPhone though, it's on a Mac.  It may be useful to note that the behavior doesn't seem as prevalent on a Linux machine

Comment: Is the application by any chance multithreaded?  Not sure how you arrive at a stack overflow from the above error, it seems to indicate a bad read or write. Even if C++11 (and a compliant compiler), your code still isn't thread safe.

Comment: Yes it is multithreaded

Comment: Note, EXC_BAD_ACCESS seems to be just Apple's name for what's otherwise called a "[segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)" or "access violation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said your code is multi-threaded. Because of the function-static `map` instance, `getEnumElementsStringRepresentation` is not re-entrant (usually). You would have to protect the function with a mutex, or use thread-local storage.